# Show a toast message when entering a number in Edit text

Tags: android, if-statement, numbers, toast

I'd like to show a toast message when entering a number less than 180 , I'm a beginner but I need some help , so i want to show a specific message when entering a number less than 180 , so what to write in the if method ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText ed1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);



}

public void mansaf (View v)
{

    if (){

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        else 
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message2 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}

}
```

and this is the xml code :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="ما السرعة التي تقود بها عادة ؟" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="ما مستوى قيادتي ؟" 
    android:onClick="mansaf"/>
```

Comment: On some button click?

Comment: @berserk yes when i click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the text with 180 by:

```
if(Integer.valueOf(ed1.getText().toString())<180)

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Message",Tosat.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: @AbdullahADhaim Sorry its getText()

Comment: if(String.valueOf(ed1.getText().toString())<180)

Comment: The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Comment: @AbdullahADhaim OOps it was Integer, how stupid of me :(

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Integer.valueof( ed1.getText().toString)<180))
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else  
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message2 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the edit is empty :)

Comment: yes, but this is not relevant to pointing him in the right direction

Comment: what is 180 there by the way?

Comment: given in the question